# Import dump file schema not found

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, import, datapump

I want to import a dump file but I have this ***error***:

> ```
> Import: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mar. Nov. 28 10:12:56 2017
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connect : Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
> ORA-39002: invalid operation
> ORA-39165: Schema TEST_2 was not found.
> ```

***My command line:***

```
impdp TEST/TEST@RECT0E DIRECTORY=DUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=Fichier.20171123_151835.dpdmp LOGFILE=TEST_2_27112017.log FULL=N EXCLUDE=STATISTICS REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEST_DATA:TEST_DATA_TEST REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEST_INDEX:TEST_INDEX_TEST REMAP_SCHEMA=TESTPR:TEST_2 SCHEMAS=TEST_2
```

***I confirm my schema exist:***

```
SELECT username FROM all_users ORDER BY username;
```

***Result:***

```
USERNAME
------------------------------
TEST
TEST_2
TEST_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `TESTPR` [SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#i1007024) so, change the value of `SCHEMAS` parameter to `TESTPR` as shown below. You have given `TEST_2` to the `SCHEMAS` which is not included in the dump file thus you have hit the error `ORA-39165`.

`...REMAP_SCHEMA=TESTPR:TEST_2 SCHEMAS=TESTPR`